# Is it strictly necessary to implement a security token cache in a WIF + Web Farm scenario?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, wif, web-farm

We're trying to implement WIF in a .Net 4.5 web farm. We are using [shared machine keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545457%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to allow multiple nodes to decrypt the FedAuth cookie. We're running into some issues with this and are in the process of debugging them.

As we've been looking for blog posts/articles/docs describing WIF + web farm configurations, we often see mentions of shared token caches. Many describe the caches as beneficial for performance or for dealing with too-large cookies. However, others seem to suggest that it is strictly necessary in order to get WIF working *at all.* From the MSDN article above:

> In [a web farm] scenario, the default WIF settings ... will not work because both token protection **and token caching** are dependent on a specific computer.

Emphasis mine.

So, my question is: is it strictly necessary to implement a shared token cache in order to make WIF work in a web farm? If so, can you help me understand the nature and purpose of the cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token cache is only needed when you want to cache the tokens on the server.

The SAM supports a mode called "reference tokens" - using this the cookie only contains an identifier whereas the actual principal (+ bootstrap context if used) is cached on the server.

WIF's default implementation of that cache is local in-memory, thus the shared cache requirements for web farms. But only if reference mode is used - which is not the default.

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct to say that token caching in any form is disabled by default?

Comment: Well - the token cache is always used, but if the token is not found, it will automatically fall back to the "on the wire" token.

Comment: That was the missing link for me. Thank you!